# Tricolorability of knots: Are there knots of arbitrary large k-colorability?

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

The trefoil knot is [tricolorable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tricolorable.html): 
In a projection, 
with at least two colors used to color its "strands,"
at every (degree-$3$) crossing, either all three colors come together,
or all three strands have the same color.
The figure-$8$ knot is not tricolorable: It needs $4$ colors.

---

[image: Fig-8]

      

<sup>Image from [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tricolorability).</sup>

---

> ***Q***. Are there knots that require $k$ colors, for arbitrarily large $k$?

I assume the answer is *Yes*, in which case examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @bof: Good point. Let me rephrase the definition, which was inaccurate (leaving off the requirement that at least two colors are used).

Comment: [Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colorable+knot#colourability_3) is an interesting generalization to $n$ colors, that is preserved by Reidemeister moves, and thus is a knot invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Breiland, Oesper, and Taalman, in [this paper](http://educ.jmu.edu/~taalmala/breil_oesp_taal.pdf), Theorem 1 says:

> Suppose $T_{m,n}$ is a torus knot and $p$ is prime.
>
> 1. If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then $T_{m,n}$ is not $p$-colorable.
> 2. If $m$ is odd and $n$ is even, then $T_{m,n}$ is $p$-colorable
>      if and only if $p|m$

This gives us that for any prime $m$, $T_{m,2}$ is $m$-colorable.  I am sure that there are other good examples, but here is a positive answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks! Cited paper: Breiland, Anna-Lisa, Layla Oesper, and Laura Taalman. "p-Coloring classes of torus knots." *Missouri Journal of Mathematical Sciences*. 21.2 (2009): 120-126.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the torus knot T_p,1 for arbitratily large p. It's p-colorable.  --Ken Perko